# Sending element id's upon form submit

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to take the data I get from an element id pulled from dropped items (using jqueryui draggables/droppables/sortables) to be sent via a form (to be emailed) along with data here:

```
      function submitForm() {
$.ajax({type:'POST',
       url: 'send_tile.php',
       data:$('#tiles_collected').serialize(), 
       success: function(response) {
    $('#tiles_collected').find('.form_result').html(response);
}});

return false;
   }
```

the function for getting the ids is this (not sure if it works right yet either):

```
  function getSku() {
var myIds = new array();
        $("#collection li").each(function(index, element){
              alert($(this).attr('id'));
           myIds.push(element.id);

            });
```

and the form looks like this:

```
     <form id="tiles_collected" name='tiles_collected' method="post" onsubmit="return submitForm();">
      Email:<input name='email' id='email' type='text'/><br />
      Name:<input name='name' id='name' type='text' /><br />
       Zip code: <input name='zip' id='zip' type='text' /><br />
       <input type='hidden' id='sku' />
       <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Email collection to yourself and us" /><br/>
       <div class="form_result"></div>
       </form>
```

Can anyone give me an assist?

Comment: And where are you using myIds array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To just add the ID's to the data sent to the server you can use extend or just add them in the Ajax function.

extend:

```
function submitForm() {
    var MyData = $('#tiles_collected').serialize();
    $.extend(MyData, {IDs: myIds});  //myIds will have to be accessable, right now it's a local variable in your getSku() function

    $.ajax({type:'POST',
       url: 'send_tile.php',
       data: MyData, 
       success: function(response) {
            $('#tiles_collected').find('.form_result').html(response);
       }
    });
    return false;
}
```

or just add them directly:

```
function getSku() {
    var myIds = new array();
    $("#collection li").each(function(index, element){
        myIds.push(element.id);
    });
    return myIds;
}

var IDs = getSku();

$.ajax({type:'POST',
    url: 'send_tile.php',
    data: {data : $('#tiles_collected').serialize(), ids : IDs},
    success: function(response) {
        $('#tiles_collected').find('.form_result').html(response);
    }
});
```

Comment: On your second example in the send_tile.php, do I just refer to it as ' ids' to actually get those values to print onto the email.

Comment: Yes, in PHP the values sent in the ajax function is available in $_POST['ids'] etc. Just do a print_r($_POST) to see what it holds or a variable dump etc.

Comment: the $('tiles_collected').serialize() doesn't seem to work anymore using that method and I'm still not seeing any of the 'ids'

Comment: You will have to change your serverside scripts for that to work, as the serialized form will now be in the $_POST['data'] variable, and not just $_POST, and the ID's will be in $_POST['IDs']. IMO this is the way to go, sending the data to the server so it's accessable in $_POST['something'], but then you will have to change your serverside code to capture those values.

Comment: I got the form values to show after I fixed the php file, thx. But I couldn't get the ids to show up. I think it's because my getSku() function is not showing the ids like it should. Bad function I guess.